# Seiberg Witten to Vortex equations

Tags: reference-request, 4-manifolds

Looking for a reference which discusses vortex equations on a compact Riemann surface as dimensional reductions of the Seiberg-Witten equations on four manifolds.

Comment: You need to detail what you mean by dimensional reduction.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu SW equations can be applied on $\Sigma\times \mathbb{R}^2$, $\Sigma$ being a surface and the equations are invariant in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ direction. I also thought there's some standard way to do it mentioned here at point 3 :https://mathoverflow.net/a/115724/131004

Comment: The noncompactness adds  a few difficulties

Comment: I would be happy to find any other reduction may be from $\Sigma\times S^2$ or $\Sigma\times S^1\times S^1$ or any such form. I thought there must be some standard result as mentioned in the link I mentioned.

Comment: Try [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01486), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9703057).

Comment: @Tyrone: Why not posting it as an answer?